# Doctrine Assocation Mapping Join Not Executing In ZF3

Tags: join, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3

I am creating my first **Association Mapping** for a Join.  This is also the first time I've used a Foreign Key in pgSQL.

I am working with ZF3.  The error I am receiving is:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT p0_.reference AS reference_0, p0_.meta_keyword_reference AS meta_keyword_reference_1, p0_.add_date AS add_date_2, p0_.add_membership_reference AS add_membership_reference_3, p0_.remove_date AS remove_date_4, p0_.remove_membership_reference AS remove_membership_reference_5 FROM page_about_meta_keyword_link p0_ INNER JOIN meta_keyword m1_':
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...page_about_meta_keyword_link p0_ INNER JOIN meta_keyword m1_
```

The query I am trying to create is

```
SELECT MetaKeywords.Keyword FROM PageAboutMetaKeywordLink INNER JOIN MetaKeywords ON PageAboutMetaKeywordLink.MetaKeywordReference = MetaKeywords.Reference WHERE PageAboutMetaKeywordLink.RemoveDate IS NULL ORDER BY MetaKeywords.Keyword ASC
```

From my database experience I expect it is creating the error due to the missing

```
ON p0_.meta_keyword_reference = m1_reference
```

I don't understand how to communicate the Join.  Based on the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html) I had expected this was automatic.  Maybe I misunderstood.

The tables I am trying to Join are page_about_meta_keyword_link.meta_keyword_reference ON meta_keyword.reference .  This is the first time I've created a foreign key in pgSQL.

This is the table structure for **page_about_meta_keyword_lin**k

```
CREATE TABLE public.page_about_meta_keyword_link
(
  reference bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('page_about_meta_keyword_link_reference_seq'::regclass),
  meta_keyword_reference bigint,
  add_date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(), -- UTC
  add_membership_reference bigint,
  remove_date timestamp with time zone, -- UTC
  remove_membership_reference bigint,
  CONSTRAINT page_about_meta_keyword_link_pkey PRIMARY KEY (reference),
  CONSTRAINT page_about_meta_keyword_link_fk FOREIGN KEY (meta_keyword_reference)
  REFERENCES public.meta_keyword (reference) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT page_about_meta_keyword_link_reference_unique UNIQUE (reference)
)
```

This is the **meta_keyword**

```
CREATE TABLE public.meta_keyword
(
  reference bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('meta_keyword_reference_seq'::regclass),
  keyword text,
  effective_date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(), -- UTC
  membership_reference bigint,
  CONSTRAINT meta_keyword_pkey PRIMARY KEY (reference),
  CONSTRAINT meta_keyword_reference_unique UNIQUE (reference)
)
```

This is the query I've created in the Service; The complete **Service** is found [here](https://github.com/rpiggott/soartheskies/blob/master/module/About/src/Service/PageAboutMetaKeywordRepository.php).

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PageAboutMetaKeywordLink::class);
$keywords = $this->entityManager->getRepository(MetaKeyword::class);

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l');
             $qb ->join('\Application\Entity\MetaKeyword' , 'k')
                 ->expr()->isNull('l.removeDate');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The Association Mapping I created is for meta_keyword_reference; The complete Entity is found [here](https://github.com/rpiggott/soartheskies/blob/master/module/Application/src/Entity/PageAboutMetaKeywordLink.php).

```
/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MetaKeyword")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meta_keyword_reference", referencedColumnName="reference")
 * @ORM\Column(name="meta_keyword_reference", type="bigint", nullable=true)
 */
private $metaKeywordReference;
```

I have not made any changes to the MetaKeywords Entity.  It is found [here](https://github.com/rpiggott/soartheskies/blob/master/module/Application/src/Entity/MetaKeywords.php).

Overall the various sections of the web site will share the meta_keywords.  If I understand correctly the connection I am trying to make is ManyToOne.

I am wanting to leave a good reference for other newbies as they are their journey with Zend Framework 3 - Doctrine.  Please advise of edits I should be making to this post so it is clear, understandable and concise so I receive the help I need and others will benefit from this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double declared a column (`meta_keyword_reference`). Looking at [the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) (same page you linked in question), you've made a mistake in your Annotation. Remove the `ORM\Column` line (the definition is already in `JoinColumn`). If you need it to be nullable (not required), add `nullable=true` to the `JoinColumn`; use either, not both

```
/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MetaKeyword")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meta_keyword_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $metaKeywordReference;
```

Do not worry about declaring a "type", Doctrine will automatically match it to the column you're referencing. Also, you should be referencing Primary Keys. I've assumed `reference` is **not** the PK, so I've changed it to `id`, change it to what it actually is.

Next, I think you're also using DBAL QueryBuilder instead of the ORM QueryBuilder.

The Query you need would be like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

/** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('l')
   ->from(PageAboutMetaKeywordLink::class, 'l')
   ->join(MetaKeyword::class, 'k', Join::ON, 'l.reference = k.id') // check these property names (NOT DB COLUMNS!)
   ->where('l.removeDate is null');
```

Might be a few small errors in there, but that should be about it.